Issue with #name error in vba code for excel
I am running the VBA code, but when I actually run it and pass it the variables, it gives me a #name? error, and I am not sure why. normally, in my experience that is calling the function wrong, but I have imported the dictionary from the json so i am not exactly sure why. as my function is spelled correctly and I am passing it cells, so those cannot be spelled incorrectly.
 Returns the number of seconds it would take to get from one place to another
Function TRAVELTIME(origin, destination, apiKey)
 
    Dim strUrl As String
    strUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" & origin & "&destination=" & destination & "&key=" & apiKey
     
    Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With httpReq
         .Open "GET", strUrl, False
         .Send
    End With
     
    Dim response As String
    response = httpReq.ResponseText
     
    Dim parsed As Dictionary
    Set parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
    Dim seconds As Integer

    Dim leg As Dictionary
     
    For Each leg In parsed("routes")(1)("legs")
        seconds = seconds + leg("duration")("value")
    Next leg
     
     
     
    TRAVELTIME = seconds
 
End Function

I have the function in the module 1, as seen below, and I am just calling it in the worksheet =traveltime(orgin, destination, apikey)



Where do you get the #Name-error? Do you use the function as UDF in a sheet? Where is the function code, in  a regular module?  Btw: Don't write text in AllCaps, that's seen as "shouting" and there is no reason to shout at us. And given the fact that SO is a long living, world wide project, saying "morning" just because it's morning in your time zone sounds strange to me (for me currently it's lunch time)

@FunThomas I updated it above. sorry about the caps.

#NAME means that Excel doesn't know the function. Possible reasons are that the function is not in a regular module (of the same workbook), it is declared as Private or that you have a typo in the name. It has nothing to do with the code of the function, if that fails with a runtime error, you would get a #VALUE-error. Unrelated: Why do you have a Dictionary-class? You probably want to use Scripting.Dictionary? Can imagine that the JSONConverter stumbles about that.

@FunThomas - to enable Mac support, VBA JSON links to a replacement for Scripting Dictionary called VBA-Dictionary  https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary   Suspect OP is using that.

Have you successfully compiled your VB project?  Can you call your function from a Sub?

@TimWilliams Ah, I always forget that there are people around using Excel on a Mac

@FunThomas the code above is truly all the code I have written so i know its not private. when i call the function inside of a call =TRAVELDISTANCE() and put in two address it autocompletes the function so i know its seeing it and its spelled right. you asked about the scripting part, i edited the post and put a picture of the tools options i have enabled. i am literally stumped. i see hundreds of people stating they literally have the exact same code and it works but I am getting that name error. i am using windows with excel not a mac.
